# Annotation/Label size adjusting to map scale in QGIS

Tags: qgis, labeling, scale, annotation

[image]I'm trying to label the street names for a map I'm working on but I do not want the labels to automatically adjust to the map scale when zooming in or out. My question is: In QGIS how do I set a fixed scale for the labels so that it wont change with the map scale?
In the labeling properties I have checked the box "Scale-based visibility" under the rendering tab but it doesn't seem to affect it at all.

Comment: Also I'm trying to get these labels to stay in the purple boxes but they move around as I zoom in/out or pan around.